# 404 Error in Magento extension when deployed in production

Tags: magento, module, http-status-code-404, admin

This one is puzzling me for 2 days now. I've found a solution for a 404 in admin, but it is not the same that is happening here. I have exactly the same version of Magento in my local copy and production server: 1.7.0.2. The extension works great in local. I packaged it using Magento Connect and installed in production the same way. All files are there.  It shows in the menu and in Configuration section, but when I click the menu to go to the report, I get the beloved 404. I loged out and in, flushed cache zillion times (including deleting the files manually) but nothing changed.This are the URLs in both envs:

```
(Dev)http://localhost/magentos/index.php/salestaxes/adminhtml_salestaxes/index/key/c4b8ecb58fa2062f696cacfd340/

(Prod)https://www.myserver.com/index.php/salestaxes/adminhtml_salestaxes/index/key/332e617e74a92a39a40cf5d3/
```

As you can see is exactly the same. I don't know wahy then I'm getting the error. Can somebody point what can I do to solve this? DO I need to check any setting? What can cause this?

This is a var_dump that I get in the router _validateControllerClassName() method:

```
string(115) "/home_path/public_html/app/code/community/Surpassweb/SalesTaxes/controllers/Adminhtml/SalestaxesController.php" 
string(100) "/home_path/public_html/app/code/community/Surpassweb/SalesTaxes/controllers/IndexController.php"
```

This is the output of Alam's 404 module:

Controller Name

```
Controller Name: adminhtml_salestaxes
The controller name adminhtml_salestaxes matches the following controller file, but this file does not exist.
home_path/public_html/app/code/community/MyCompany/SalesTaxes/controllers/Adminhtml/SalestaxesController.php
```

The file is there and has 755 permissions.

This is the first line in may controller:

```
class MyCompany_SalesTaxes_Adminhtml_SalesTaxesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which 404 page are you seeing? (http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages).  If it's the no route 404 page, my free Programmer's 404 module may be able to help you. (http://alanstorm.com/magento-404-debug). This module replaces the no route 404 with diagnostic information.

Comment: I'm checking your suggestions @AlanStorm. Thanks for taking time to help me.

Comment: Updated question to include your very useful 404 module's output, @AlanStorm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure the file is there?  Named the same?  With the same character capitalization?  And that you're not in a production setup with multiple frontend webservers?

If you'll indulge me — copy the path of the controller from the Better 404 page to your computer's clipboard.  Then type

```
$ ls -l [PASTE]
```

into your terminal window.  My bet if the file won't be there.  Also try

```
$ls -l app/code/community/Surpassweb/SalesTaxes/controllers/Adminhtml/
```

to see what files are there.

Looking at the information you provided, Magento is looking for a file named

```
app/code/community/MyCompany/SalesTaxes/controllers/Adminhtml/SalestaxesController.php
```

I don't know what your actual file is named, but looking at the class name

```
MyCompany_SalesTaxes_Adminhtml_SalesTaxesController
```

leads me to believe it *might* be incorrectly named `SalesTaxesControlle.php`.  Notice the `T` in sales taxes is capitalized, vs the lowercase `t` Magento is looking for.

Comment: I don't have SSH access, but this is the route for the file taken from the file browser in cPanel: public_html/app/code/community/MyCompany/SalesTaxes/controllers/adminhtml/SalesTaxesController.php. I changed it to SalestaxesController.php but same error after login in and out (cache deactivated).

Comment: What is annoying though, is that it works with SalesTaxesController in local copy and I don't have Salestaxes in my config in any place.

Comment: @BlessedBoy I'm guessing your local computer is a Mac with a case aware, but non-case sensitive file system.  It's a common problem.  If its the same error then you still have a naming problem. ls -l, remove one file part at a time until you find something, and then name your files the way Magento wants them (FYI, this is why most experienced Magento developers avoid CamelCasing class name parts). Good luck!

Comment: The camel case comes from almost all the examples in the web. I'm new to Magento and every tutorial (most of them from 2012 or before) use camel case. Thanks for all the help anyway. I really appreciate your insight and now I know that I'll figure it out. The OS is Windows.

Comment: Would you consider, @AlanStorm, taking a peek at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494091/what-fileds-in-magento-should-use-to-get-tax-dollar-amount-collected-total-sal ? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I choose this question because it points in the right direction, but finally solved the issue using moduleCreator.It helps in avoiding all the naming problems @AlanStorm talks about.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason magento isn't registering the route to your app.

Either apache doesn't know to let magento handle it or magento doesn't know what to do with it.

Check your htaccess files and virtual host configs for the two environments.

Right off the bat I can see they're not exactly the same. One is http and one is https.
Those are probably two different virtual host configs and could be slightly different.

Next I would make sure the config xml for your module is included in magento/app/etc/modules/ folder. Make sure the module is enabled. There should be a line for that in your modules config xml file.

If you deployed it to the local vs community folder, check the magento/app/etc/local.xml and make sure disable_local_modules is set to no.

Good luck. Troubleshooting in live is always fun.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'll check those things

Comment: OK, all checked and nothing pops up as a solution. The module is correctly registered. Otherwise it were not in the menu.

Comment: @BlessedBoy Two last things, the `C` in controller should always be capitolized (controller names are weird/special in Magento), and the reason camel casing is bas has less to do with a limitation of Magento, it's just that it's easy to accidentally not capitalize a word.  Happy coding.